# Ajax success function location.reload for individual php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a feed page on my website (very similar to facebook) that enables me to like and comment on posts. I'm using ajax to update the posts, however, after a like, rather than each individual post reloading, the whole feed does (not the whole page itself, it just returns to the top of the feed).

I believe this is because each post is using a file named `feedLikes.php` that are all being reloaded rather than just that one specific post. I'm not sure how to only make that one post reload. below is my code.

From `feed.php` below, you can see i am searching for all the posts within the database. Each one of these posts is given a feedID like so:

```
$findShouts = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM feed WHERE name IN (SELECT scoutingUsername FROM scout WHERE scoutedUsername =? OR scoutingUsername =?)  ORDER BY timestamp DESC');

//execute query and variables
$findShouts->execute([$username, $username]);


if ($findShouts->rowCount() > 0)
    {    

//get the shouts for each scout
while($row = $findShouts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

$shoutID[]              = $row['id'];
$shoutUsername[]        = $row["username"];
$shoutName[]            = $row["name"];
$shoutText[]            = $row["text"]; 
$shoutTimestamp[]       = $row["timestamp"];  
} 


$shoutCount = count($shoutUsername); 


for($indexShout=0; $indexShout < $shoutCount; $indexShout++) {        


print'
<div class=feedNewShout>


<div class=shoutInformation>

<div class=shoutName>
<p>'. $shoutName[$indexShout] .'</p>
</div>

<div class=shoutTimestamp>
<p>'. timeElapsed("$shoutTimestamp[$indexShout]", 2) .'</p>
</div>

<div class=shoutText>
<p>'. $shoutText[$indexShout] .'</p>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="feedID" class="feedID" value="'. $shoutID[$indexShout] .'">


<div class=likesAndComments>


<div class=likesAjax data-id="'.$shoutID[$indexShout] .'">
</div>

<div class=commentsAjax data-id="'.$shoutID[$indexShout] .'">
</div>

<div class=deleteShoutAjax data-id="'.$shoutID[$indexShout] .'">
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>';

}
unset($shoutID);
unset($shoutUsername);
unset($shoutName);
unset($shoutText);
unset($shoutTimestamp);
}
```

From this i use a jquery Ajax call in `feedLikesAjax.js` to find each individual feedID needed:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
$(".likesAjax").each(function() {
    var feedID = $(this).attr("data-id");


 $.ajax({
  url: "feedLikes.php",
  cache: false,
    type: "POST",
     data: {feedID: feedID},
     dataType: "html",
  success: function(html){
    $(".likesAjax[data-id='"+ feedID +"']").empty();  
    $(".likesAjax[data-id='"+ feedID +"']").append(html);
  }
});
}); 

});
```

I use this information and pass it to `feedLikes.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['feedID']))

    {

 $feedID = ($_POST['feedID']);


$findHasUserLiked = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM feedLikes WHERE feedID =? and username=?');

//execute query and variables
$findHasUserLiked->execute([$feedID, $username]);

if ($findHasUserLiked->rowCount() > 0)
    { 

$hasUserLiked = $findHasUserLiked->fetchColumn();

echo<<<_END

<form action="feedLikes.php" id="unlikePostForm$feedID" method="post">

<button type="submit" class="unLikeButton"></button>

<input type="hidden" name="feedIDForUnlike" class="feedIDForUnlike$feedID" value="$feedID">

</form>

_END;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $('#unlikePostForm<?php echo $feedID ?>').on('submit', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();

var feedIDUnlike = $(".feedIDForUnlike<?php echo $feedID ?>").val();



     $.ajax({
      url: "feedLikesClicked.php",
      cache: false,
        type: "POST",
         data: {feedIDUnlike: feedIDUnlike},
         dataType: "html",
      success: function(html){
    location.reload();
      }
    });
    });
});

</script>

<?php

}

 else

 {

echo<<<_END

 <form action="feedLikes.php" id="likePostForm$feedID" method="post">

<button type="submit" class="likeButton"></button>


<input type="hidden" name="feedIDForLike" class="feedIDForLike$feedID" value="$feedID">

</form>

_END;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $('#likePostForm<?php echo $feedID ?>').on('submit', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();

var feedIDLike = $(".feedIDForLike<?php echo $feedID ?>").val();



     $.ajax({
      url: "feedLikesClicked.php",
      cache: false,
        type: "POST",
         data: {feedIDLike: feedIDLike},
         dataType: "html",
      success: function(html){
    location.reload();
      }
    });
    });
});

</script>

<?php

 }


 $likesNumber = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM feedLikes WHERE feedID =?');

//execute query and variables
$likesNumber->execute([$feedID]);

$numberOfLikes = $likesNumber->fetchColumn();

print'
<div class=numberOfLikes data-id="'.$feedID .'">
<p>'. $numberOfLikes .'</p>
</div>';

}

?>
```

Like i said it all works perfectly apart from the reloading. Now i know the location.reload that is used on success is actually reloading every `feedLikes.php` for every post. But i'm really stuck on how to just reload the current `feedLikes.php` post that is needed for that specific post. I thought this would be really simple, and it maybe, but i cant find it anywhere.

Really grateful for any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. To achieve what you are actually asking you need to modify your jQuery success function to target only the div element for the post you are interested in. Either by adding a unique ID to the HTML, or using a selector based on the class and data-id attributes to identify that specific post.

Then yout PHP needs to only return the HTML which you want to modify and you have your jQuery success function insert that into the div for the relevant post.

Having said that, for what you are trying to do is there really any need to reload the post? You could have your PHP script just return the new number of likes and whether or not current user has liked the post and then update those values in your success call.

You could optimise your code a lot, the `feedLikesAjax.js` script is calling `feedLikes.php` once the page is loaded, creating a new ajax request for each post. You could combine the code from `feedLikes.php` into `feed.php` and have the server output the page with all the data immediately, and get rid of `feedLikesAjax.js` altogether. You could replace the likes and unlikes forms with a single button for each post and right now you are setting an event handler for each form individually, if you give them all a common class you can just use a single event handler.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment:

You don't need another query in your while statement. You can expand your first query using a left join to have it also include data from the feedLikes table in the returned results or you can use another subquery to your original query to add another column to your returned results. Something along the lines of this should give you a userLiked row with a value of 1 or 0 for liked/not liked. You might have to edit it a bit to get it working for you, I'm not an SQL guru by any means.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(L.username) FROM feedLikes L WHERE L.feedID = F.id AND L.username = F.username) AS userLiked
FROM feed F
WHERE name IN (SELECT scoutingUsername FROM scout WHERE scoutedUsername =? OR scoutingUsername =?)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Hi, the reason i have a separate file for feedLikes is because i was told i couldn't have a query within a 'while' statement which would be needed to find out the like count of each post within feed.php? Also, I'm having trouble with trying to get a selector based on the class and data-id to work :/ sorry I am new to code and appreciate the help. Thank you